# My CMS page redirects to homepage - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages, redirect-url

Hi i've modified a **page url** to my **page name**. I've also changed the url link present on my navigation menu **eg**: I've changed the page url `about-magento-demo-store` to `about-us`. But when I click on the link it doesn't work and it keeps on redirecting me to my shop homepage.

I've re-indexed it so many times and flushed my cache but it still doesn't work.

Can anyone help please?

Magento **CE 1.9.3.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help guys, I've fixed this issue. Actually i've installed an multi-seller extension which was causing the redirection problem. I've contacted the developer and my issue was fixed by changing a small line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make change in following config

**System > Configuration > Web > Search Engines Optimization**

Use Web Server Rewrites to **No**

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to the database then **truncate** `core_url_rewrite`.

2) **Reindex** direclty via admin panel Or ssh like this: `php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall`.

3) **Refresh** your Magento and navigator cache. It should work and you will no longer have your error.

**EDIT:**

The cms page has been redirected temporarily to the home page, please check these:

- System > Configuration > Web > URL Option and change `Auto-redirect to Base URL` to No.
- System > Configuration > Advanced check if `Mage_Cms` is not disabled

Comment: I've tried it as said but still no luck...all my categories links are working but not the new pages links created by me for reference you can visit my site eshopportal.com, there you can see on the top navigation menu...i've added about us page but it is not working. Whereas contact us page is working

Comment: The `About us`page has been redirected temporarily to the homepage because there is some issue, look my update

Comment: I've done as you have said, but still it is not working....can you tell me why my contact page is working?

Comment: contact page is not a `cms page` but a module who have a frontname=`contacts`

Comment: try to create a new cms page, don't update some exsistant one

Comment: I have done as you said but it is still not working. For reference visit www,eshopportal.com

Comment: Hi, I've created a new cms page as you've said but still the result is same. For reference visit [link](http://www.eshopportal.com)

Answer (score 0):

One another thing that you need to remember is if you're site is accessed on https like

https://www.yourdomain.com/

> You should also make sure that the base Link URL should be on https
>   too. Otherwise Magento .htaccess rules will redirect you back to the
>   Base Url

So the bottom line is  **URL Base Link** under system - configuration - web - HTTP should be https://www.yourdomain.com/

After this clean / refresh your cache and reload your pages, This time magento wont reidrect you to home page.

> web/unsecure/base_link_url

If you dont want to do this, then you need to change the .htaccess rules as shown in this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/25528651/777103